# Duplicate instances for same entity in Neo4j OGM

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am having problems upgrading from Spring Boot 2.0.8 to 2.3.11 / Spring Data Neo4j 5.0.13 to 5.3.9.

I have a REST API with CRUD operations for my entities, and use Jackson `ObjectIdResolver`s to resolve related entities from id's in the incoming JSON request. The entities have a custom id field of type UUID, and the resolvers use Neo4j repositories to lookup the entities by the UUID key.

In my case, 3 entities are related:

`(A)--(B)--(C)`

`A` has a list of `B`, and `B` has a list of `C`. `POST` to create a new `C`:

```
{
  "name": "My C",
  "b": "c3c9ec23-ff05-4295-9b5b-209af08328ac"
}
```

The resolver for `B` will lookup the entity and populate my instance of `C`. If I do a specific `findById` for `B` within the resource, I get the same instance as I had from the resolver - which is exactly what I want.

Now, when upgrading to Spring Data 5.3.9, I get a different result. A new lookup in the rest controller will return a second instance representing the same entity that was loaded by the resolver - with the same ID and UUID. Seems like the instance loaded by the resolver is not in the mapping context. This causes problems in the save since `C` references an instance that is not in the context, and typically it causes relationships to be deleted.

Specifically, the instance `B` loaded by the resolver has an instance of `A`, but `A` is not fully loaded (the list of `B` only contains one single instance, the others are not loaded). A lookup of `A` in the rest controller will return an instance with fully loaded the list of `B`. Saving the new `C` with the `B` reference from the resolver will cause relationships between `A` and `B` to be deleted.

How can I get the instance from the resolver into the mapping context? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by explicitly setting `spring.data.neo4j.open-in-view: true` in `application.yaml`, since the default has been changed.

See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/881 for more details.